# oilabs package installation error

Tags: r, package, permutation, statistics-bootstrap

hope this isn't a bad question.

I have been trying to download the "oilabs" package to use the rep_n_sample function for permutation and bootstrapping. However, every time I try to install it I get the error that the package is not available (for R version 3.4.0). I tried to download it from github [HERE](https://github.com/OpenIntroOrg/oilabs/tree/master/R) but I can't use the library() function to retrieve it (from package archive file) as it says there is no package called oilabs-master even though I'm extracting it from the same folder I installed it in. If anyone has an alternative function for rep_n_sample that would also be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need is that function, why don't you just copy-paste it from github into your console. All the calls it makes seem to be either in base R or `dplyr`, so it should work.

You can find the function [here](https://github.com/OpenIntroOrg/oilabs/blob/master/R/rep_sample_n.R)

Comment: Hi Yannis, I have tried it earlier but forgot update my RStudio so it didn't work. Thanks!